# How to pass date variable in uri for Microsoft graph request?

Tags: string, date, uri, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get back a list of calendar events with Microsoft Graph API but having problems with passing date variable in the query parameters.
If I hardcode the uri value to:

```
uri: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/calendar/events?$filter=start/dateTime ge ' + `'2018-12-10T19:30:34.654Z'`,
```

then the request works. But if I try to pass the date variable with toISOString, I get an error. I've tried with or without backticks, and calling toISOString in the uri value and in the nextMonday function. Still doesn't work. Anyone have any ideas? Thanks!

```
function nextMonday(date){
      var monday = new Date(date);
      monday.setDate(monday.getDate() + (1 + 7 - monday.getDay()) % 7);
      return monday.toISOString();
    }

    let date = new Date();
    let m = nextMonday(date);

    const options = {
      uri: 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/calendar/events?$filter=start/dateTime ge ' + `m`,
      auth: {
        bearer: token,
      },
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'application/json'
      },
      json: true // Automatically parses the JSON string in the response
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to (1) use ${m} to add the value and (2) wrap it in single quotes.

uri: `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/calendar/events?$filter=start/dateTime ge '${m}'`,